# What's the meaning of the __setattr__ in this Python code?

Tags: python

```
class Local(object):
__slots__ = ('__storage__', '__ident_func__')

def __init__(self):
    object.__setattr__(self, '__storage__', {})
    object.__setattr__(self, '__ident_func__', get_ident)

def __call__(self, proxy):
    """Create a proxy for a name."""
    return LocalProxy(self, proxy)

def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError(name)

def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    ident = self.__ident_func__()
    storage = self.__storage__
    try:
        storage[ident][name] = value
    except KeyError:
        storage[ident] = {name: value}

def __delattr__(self, name):
    try:
        del self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

I want to know the difference between `__setattr__` magic function and `self.__xxx__ = {}`.
Now I put more code here.In the constructor,it's object.**setattr**.So does the overwritten have some influence to it ?

Comment: Is that the entire class? It’s calling `object.__setattr__`, so `Local` could have its own overridden `__setattr__`.

Comment: Does your class have an override of `__setattr__` elsewhere? Otherwise, I'm pretty sure either version is equivalent (the version that avoids `object.__setattr__` being better, but still poor form, since [names beginning and ending with `__` are reserved for the language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers)).

Comment: @Mr.J: Though those uses are needed for avoiding infinite recursion when implementing `__setattr__` itself. Not typically needed for `__init__`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger fat finger :)

Comment: .In the constructor,it's object.setattr.So does the overwritten have some influence to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Like almost all `__...__` classes, `__setattr__` is basically designed to be overridden in inheriting classes to change how a Python class works. If changing the semantics of `x.foo` wasn't needed, `__setattr__` might not exist. `x.foo` is defined as `__setattr__` on self; so it could do anything (e.g. set up DB fields like in Django).

But notice that the code in the question calls `object.__setattr__`, not the one on `self`. Thus, even if the current class overrides `__setattr__` to do something completely different, you can still use `object`'s definition of the original attribute-setting behaviour to... set an attribute.